# Email is dropping in spam folder using php mail()

Tags: php, email

```
 define("WEBMASTER_EMAIL","");<br/>

$from_Email = "garglawfirm@gmail.com";<br/>
```

//send email to the client...

```
$subject = "Trademark Registration Request";<br/>
$message = "Hi ".$client_applicantName.",<br/>
```

Your request for Trademark Registration has been received. We will Proceed it!.. 
 Your Request Id is: `".$lastInserId." and Applicant Type is: ".$client_applicantType."`
Sent by `<a href='http://www.glf.gssltd.co.in'>Garg Law Firm";`

```
$send = @mail(WEBMASTER_EMAIL, $subject, $message,
       "To: ".$client_applicantEmail."\r\n"
      ."From: ".$from_Email."\r\n"
      ."Return-path: ".$client_applicantEmail."\r\n"
      ."MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"
      ."Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n");<br/>
if($send){<br/>
       echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";<br/>
       echo "alert('Client Details Successfully Saved. Mail Sent To Your Email-Id.');window.location.href='http://glf.gssltd.co.in/search-trademark-app'";<br/>
       echo "</script>";<br/>    
      }else{<br/>
          echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";<br/>
          echo "alert('Unable to Save Client Details.');";<br/>
          echo "</script>";<br/>
      }
```

Comment: I doubt your client appreciates you posting their email address in plain text here. That's a great way to get lots of spam.

Comment: See : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/712392/send-email-using-the-gmail-smtp-server-from-a-php-page

Comment: As for your problem: you're sending from a gmail.com address, but not through a gmail server. The recipient server can check your client's site against the list of gmail.com servers, find that it's not there, and treat the email as bogus.

Comment: How to fix this problem. Please help me out?